# Recursively compress files in a directory and subdirectories using command line "zip" tool in Mac OS X and exclude .DS_Store files from ALL subfolders

Tags: macos, command-line, compression, zip, bsd

I'm trying to create a ZIP file using the command line `zip` tool that comes with the Mac OS X Terminal. I want to recursively compress the contents of the current folder but excluding `.DS_Store` files. I'm trying with this:

```
zip -r myarchive.zip . -x .DS_Store
```

The `-x .DS_Store` excludes the `.DS_Store` file in the current folder, but not in the recursively added subfolders. How do I exclude all the `.DS_Store` files from ALL subfolders as well?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add a wildcard to the exclude option

```
zip -r myarchive.zip . -x "*.DS_Store"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but, why? :). Could you please explain?

Comment: The `*` expands to nothing or any part of a path as zip recursively compresses the files and their directories. So, `./.DS_Store` then `./*/.DS_Store` and so on are excluded from the archive.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So the wildcard works differently than in the Windows world, where "*.DS_Store" would just mean "any file that ends with .DS_Store"

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times I want to exclude **all** hidden files, such as `.DS_Store` or `.git` or `.gitignore`

With one simple command you can take care of all of that and compress all files and subfolders recursively:

```
zip -r archive.zip folder -x "*/\.*"
```

In case the archive already exists, above command will overwrite existing files and add new files to the archive.

If you want to replace the archive entirely you will need the following command:

```
zip -FSr archive.zip folder -x "*/\.*"
```

Or even better, create a function in zsh to make life easier

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

Add the following code in your aliases section

```
function zip-visible(){
    zip -FSr $1 $2 -X -x "*/\.*"
}
```

Reload the zsh configuration

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Use like this

```
zip-visible archive.zip folder
```